# Set variable ftp anon_root directory in ubuntu vsftpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ftp

I have a FTP server running to let local users share files to anon users (friends and peers).

The public share folder is called `/PubRoot`.

But I do not want files to be accessed from such a predicable location - any one running a watch script can harvest whatever that is posted there. thus the actual shared folder should be unpredictable like a random string, and no one should be able to access `PubRoot` common folder.

The actual implementation should be something like: `/PubRoot/saoehuSHUSOoeusSOHeuueohs`
or
`/PubRoot/uioneuidoeneotuid`

Then anon users will access it through `ftp://<URL>/saoehuSHUSOoeusSOHeuueohs`

Right now, in my vsftpd config i have `anon_users = /PubRoot/*/`
But doesn't seems to be working.

How can I do it? I'm able to accept other possible solution to the security issue.